# Bad xml block 3 linearlayout and 2 calender

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-widget

hi i'm trying to create an xml file which includes 1- label 'task' and a text view under it for user input
2- label 'price' and a text view under it for user input
3-label 'category' and a combobox with 6 choices
4- label 'date to end' and a calender beside it 
5- label 'date to remind' and a calender beside it 
finally a button for saving
the problem is I couldn't find combobox on eclipse, the second calender and button don't appear
here is the code

xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<!-- Name Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/tsk"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/>

     <!-- Input Name -->
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"/> 

      <!-- Price Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/price"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/> 

    <!-- Input Price -->
    <EditText 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"/> 

    <!-- category Label -->
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/cat"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"/> 

    <!-- Input category -->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:lines="4" />

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:text="@string/de" />
    <Calender
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="36dp" />
      </LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="4dip"
    android:paddingBottom="6dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.00"
        android:text="@string/de" />
    <Calender
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="66dp" />
      </LinearLayout>

<!-- Button Create task -->
    <Button 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save"/> 

</LinearLayout>
```

and there are many error

```
[2013-03-30 21:46:01 - checklist] W/ResourceType(12304): Bad XML block: header size 301 or total size 0 is larger than data size 0
[2013-03-30 21:46:01 - checklist] C:\Users\Najd\workspace\checklist\res\values\strings.xml:4: error: Found tag id where item is expected
[2013-03-30 21:46:01 - checklist] C:\Users\Najd\workspace\checklist\res\layout\add_task.xml:7: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/tsk').
[2013-03-30 21:46:01 - checklist] C:\Users\Najd\workspace\checklist\res\layout\add_task.xml:24: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/price').
[2013-03-30 21:46:01 - checklist] C:\Users\Najd\workspace\checklist\res\layout\add_task.xml:42: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/cat').
[2013-03-30 21:46:01 - checklist] C:\Users\Najd\workspace\checklist\res\layout\add_task.xml:67: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/de').
[2013-03-30 21:46:01 - checklist] C:\Users\Najd\workspace\checklist\res\layout\add_task.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/save').
[2013-03-30 21:46:01 - checklist] C:\Users\Najd\workspace\checklist\res\menu\activity_main_task.xml:3: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/menu_settings').
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to strings like  `@string/save`, `@string/de` etc. but they do not exist. Add them to your strings.xml file:

```
<string name="save">Save</string>
```

Comment: Add your strings.xml file to your question

Comment: There seems to be no problem. Try saving all your files and clean your project: project > clean.

Comment: what about the second calender and button they don't appear can u find out what is the problem

Comment: @Najd Because there is no room, just keep your layout in ScrollView

Comment: You have to make layout_heigh of both LinearLayouts (with Calenders inside) **wrap_content** instead of **fill_parent**

Comment: I used one linear layout block

Comment: @Najd I can see three LinearLayouts in the provided xml: one of them is main, and other two (which i was talking about) are inner for the first.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you made a typo: string.xml should be renamed to strings.xml

Comment: That shouldn't play a role since the resource file names do not have to be called like that. It's just a convention.

Answer (score 0):

I used one linear layout , thats enough for now

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

     <!-- Name Label -->


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/tsk"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <!-- Input Name -->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <!-- Price Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/price"
        android:textSize="17dip" 
        android:gravity="right"/>

    <!-- Input Price -->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <!-- category Label -->

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dip"
        android:paddingRight="10dip"
        android:paddingTop="10dip"
        android:text="@string/cat"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <!-- Input category -->

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:lines="4" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/de" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="59dp"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/dr" />

    <CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.39"
        android:gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/save" />

</LinearLayout>
```